# Multidimentional Associative array with array values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

i wanted to covert array values into a multidimensional associative array.
Array size can be dynamic.

Array to be converted:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => 0
    [2] => xyz
    [3] => 0
)
```

Expected Output:

```
 Array
(
    [abc] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [xyz] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Tried with popping first key, but that has no luck...

Comment: Why would you want to do that? In many years I have never had the need to do something like this. Maybe the problem is in some other code you are not showing us, that requires such an output - can you show us?

Comment: Its our requirement in our application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this..

```
$tmpArr =  array('Abc', '0', 'ABC','0');
$array = array();
foreach (array_reverse($tmpArr) as $arr)
$array = array($arr => $array);
```